# Why is suffering justified in some cases if suffering is bad?

Tags: ethics

Things such as punishment make someone suffer. If suffering is bad; why is it justified to make someone suffer in some cases?

Comment: Why should anyone have to construct an argument against a bald statement of opinion? I think, "Nuh, uh." should suffice to counter it.